# How to redirect a client to a website after having authenticated it?

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I have to implement a simple *Single Sign On* (SSO) solution between two existing internet applications hosted by two different companies.

What it should do:

1. The user log into application A with his username and password.
2. The user eventually clicks on a button in application A to launch application B.
3. This button is in fact a link to a “facade” (an ASP.NET page) installed somewhere between application A and application B.
4. The facade retrieve the token (included in the URL by the caller) and call a web service of Application A with this token to get user's email. This email is included in the response.
5. The facade then retrieved the user/password of the user from a local
   database and post them to the login page of application B.
6. The facade then redirect the caller to application B.

[image: Process]

The problem is, I don’t know how to implement the last step. The response to the Post (step 5) is the Welcome page and a cookie. I’ve tried to copy this response (a `HttpWebResponse`) to the `Response` of the facade, but while the user can see the Welcom page content, there is no redirection...

```
HttpWebResponse applicationBResponse = PostApplicationB();
var reader = new treamReader(applicationBResponse.GetResponseStream());
string temp = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close(); 
Response.Write(temp);
```

Any idea how I should implement this redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way this scheme will work is if you get rid of the facade.  Instead, Application A should retrieve the user's name and password and render the to a page in hidden fields, contained in a form.  The page should conclude with a snippet of javascript to submit the form to Application B.  Application B will reply directly to the browser with the welcome page along with any session cookies.

If you use a facade, the cookies won't propagate and the end user browser will not be able to access the site.  Even if you modify your facade to pass along the cookies, they will be in the wrong domain.

Also, I must comment, this is very poor design from a security perspective.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. It was indeed a poor design and we will change it. It seems that we may have some control over Application A and Application B. I think that your solution is the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for using Windows Identity Foundation to implement what's known as **Passive Federation**.  Identity Federation the concept of having a centralized service or application in charge of managing a user's identity authenticating a user's credentials.  Relying applications can then set up a **trust relationship** with the identity service so that they are no longer concerned with how a user is authenticated.  One benefit to this approach is that if for some reason you ever decide to change your authentication mechanism, such as moving from passwords to client side certificates, none of your applications need to change **at all**.  As long as the identity service they trust says a user is good, they can keep trucking along as usual.

By using WIF, almost all of the plumbing code that you are attempting to write will be handled for you, and will likely address most of your scenarios out of the box.  It supports a number of different protocols, is highly flexible and configurable, and is easily extended should you have custom requirements not covered in a default scenario.

If you're looking for a good open source identity service, then check out [Thinktecture's Identity Server v3](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/).  You can be up and running in minutes, and is easily customizable to fit your organization and your needs.  We are using Identity Server in our organization to handle SSO for both Web and WPF applications with great success.

For a good primer on Identity Federation, check out [A Guide to Claims Based Identity and Access Control](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28362) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! WIF, Passive Federation and Identity Server are new to me. Cheers.